# Difference between the servlet http post and put method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have used POST for inserting record and PUT for updating record when handling REST webservice, but with respect to the Http Servlet what is the difference between the post and put method and when do you use put method?

Comment: PUT/POST are HTTP protocol methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest

Comment: You may consider reading REST and read about the verbs associated with HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpServlet follow the [**HTTP specs**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) as well which in simpler terms says:

**POST**: To create a resource

**PUT**: To modify a resource and if resource does not exist then create it

HttpServlet provides an implementation of POST and PUT in doPost and doPut method.

Comment: It might be worth adding that the linked HTTP spec has detailed expectations for `POST` and `PUT`, answering the second half of the question.

Comment: @bstempi The link is already there in the first sentence, let me make it bold :-)

Comment: Your answer confuses entities and resources. The wording in the RFC you cited is greatly to be preferred.

Comment: @EJP Modified the answer, hope it is inline with specs now. Feel free to do any required modifications. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

According to JavaDocs...

**HTTP POST** method allows the client to send data of unlimited length to the Web server a single time and is useful when posting information such as credit card numbers.

**PUT** operation allows a client to place a file on the server and is similar to sending a file by FTP.

hope it helps.